# Create variable of type Map[string]interface{} in gRPC protoc buffer golang

Tags: go, grpc, protoc

I'm using grpc golang to communicate between client and server application.
Below is the code for protoc buffer.

```
syntax = "proto3";
package Trail;

service TrailFunc {
  rpc HelloWorld (Request) returns (Reply) {}
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message Request {
  map<string,string> inputVar = 1;
}
// The response message containing the greetings
message Reply {
  string outputVar = 1;
}
```

I need to create a field inputVar of type map[string]interface{} inside message data structure instead of map[string]string.
How can I achieve it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Off-hand, that sounds like "you don't want to". But I guess a `map<string,google.protobuf.Any>` might work, maybe?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

proto3 has type `Any`

```
import "google/protobuf/any.proto";

message ErrorStatus {
  string message = 1;
  repeated google.protobuf.Any details = 2;
}
```

but if you look at its implementation, it is simply as

```
message Any {
  string type_url = 1;
  bytes value = 2;
}
```

You have to define such a message yourself by possibly using reflection and an intermediate type.

See [example application](https://github.com/logrusorgru/gopb3any)

https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/60

Answer (score 12):

I [wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65026774/5789008) a longer post about how to use `google.protobuf.Struct` to work with arbitrary JSON input. The `structpb` package capable to produce a `map[string]interface{}` from a `structpb.Struct` via its `AsMap()` function.

Official documentation: https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/structpb

Answer (score 4):

While it gets a little verbose to deal with, the "struct" type in protocol buffers is probably closer to golang's map[string]interface{}

But like interface{}  will take some reflection-style overhead to determine what the actual stored type is.

for example see comment here: https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/370