# Is "google/protobuf/struct.proto" the best way to send dynamic JSON over GRPC?

Tags: json, go, protocol-buffers, grpc, protoc

I have a written a simple GRPC server and a client to call the server (both in Go). Please tell me if using golang/protobuf/struct is the best way to send a dynamic JSON with GRPC.
In the example below, earlier I was creating `Details` as a `map[string]interface{}` and serializing it. Then I was sending it in protoMessage as `bytes` and was de-serializing the message on the server side.

Is it the best/efficient way to do it or should I define Details as a struct in my proto file?

Below is User.proto file

```
syntax = "proto3";
package messages;
import "google/protobuf/struct.proto";

service UserService {
    rpc SendJson (SendJsonRequest) returns (SendJsonResponse) {}
}

message SendJsonRequest {
    string UserID = 1;
    google.protobuf.Struct Details = 2;
}

message SendJsonResponse {
    string Response = 1;
}
```

Below is client.go file

```
package main
import (
    "context"
    "flag"
    pb "grpc-test/messages/pb"
    "log"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
)

func main() {
    var serverAddr = flag.String("server_addr", "localhost:5001", "The server address in the format of host:port")
    opts := []grpc.DialOption{grpc.WithInsecure()}
    conn, err := grpc.Dial(*serverAddr, opts...)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("did not connect: %s", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    userClient := pb.NewUserServiceClient(conn)
    ctx := context.Background()

    sendJson(userClient, ctx)
}

func sendJson(userClient pb.UserServiceClient, ctx context.Context) {
    var item = &structpb.Struct{
        Fields: map[string]*structpb.Value{
            "name": &structpb.Value{
                Kind: &structpb.Value_StringValue{
                    StringValue: "Anuj",
                },
            },
            "age": &structpb.Value{
                Kind: &structpb.Value_StringValue{
                    StringValue: "Anuj",
                },
            },
        },
    }

    userGetRequest := &pb.SendJsonRequest{
        UserID: "A123",
        Details: item,
    }

    res, err := userClient.SendJson(ctx, userGetRequest)
}
```

Comment: see https://blog.envoyproxy.io/dynamic-extensibility-and-protocol-buffers-dcd0bf0b8801

Answer (score 33):

Based on this proto file.

```
syntax = "proto3";
package messages;
import "google/protobuf/struct.proto";

service UserService {
    rpc SendJson (SendJsonRequest) returns (SendJsonResponse) {}
}

message SendJsonRequest {
    string UserID = 1;
    google.protobuf.Struct Details = 2;
}

message SendJsonResponse {
    string Response = 1;
}
```

I think it is a good solution to use the `google.protobuf.Struct` type.

The folks with their answers, helped me a lot at the beginning, so I would like to say thanks for your work! :) I really appreciate both solutions! :)
On the other hand, I think I found a better one to produce these kinds of `Structs`.

### Anuj's Solution

This is a little bit overcomplicated but it can work.

```
var item = &structpb.Struct{
    Fields: map[string]*structpb.Value{
        "name": &structpb.Value{
            Kind: &structpb.Value_StringValue{
                StringValue: "Anuj",
            },
        },
        "age": &structpb.Value{
            Kind: &structpb.Value_StringValue{
                StringValue: "Anuj",
            },
        },
    },
}
```

### Luke's Solution

This is a shorter one but still require more conversion than necessary. `map[string]interface{} -> bytes -> Struct`

```
m := map[string]interface{}{
  "foo":"bar",
  "baz":123,
}
b, err := json.Marshal(m)
s := &structpb.Struct{}
err = protojson.Unmarshal(b, s)
```

### The solution from my perspective

My solution will use the official functions from the `structpb` package which is pretty well documented and user friendly.

**Documentation:** https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/structpb

For example, this code creates a `*structpb.Struct` via the function that was designed to do this.

```
m := map[string]interface{}{
    "name": "Anuj",
    "age":  23,
}

details, err := structpb.NewStruct(m) // Check to rules below to avoid errors
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

userGetRequest := &pb.SendJsonRequest{
    UserID: "A123",
    Details: details,
}
```

One of the most important thing, that we should keep in mind when we are building `Struct` from a `map[string]interface{}` is this:

https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/structpb#NewValue

```
// NewValue constructs a Value from a general-purpose Go interface.
//
//  ╔════════════════════════╤════════════════════════════════════════════╗
//  ║ Go type                │ Conversion                                 ║
//  ╠════════════════════════╪════════════════════════════════════════════╣
//  ║ nil                    │ stored as NullValue                        ║
//  ║ bool                   │ stored as BoolValue                        ║
//  ║ int, int32, int64      │ stored as NumberValue                      ║
//  ║ uint, uint32, uint64   │ stored as NumberValue                      ║
//  ║ float32, float64       │ stored as NumberValue                      ║
//  ║ string                 │ stored as StringValue; must be valid UTF-8 ║
//  ║ []byte                 │ stored as StringValue; base64-encoded      ║
//  ║ map[string]interface{} │ stored as StructValue                      ║
//  ║ []interface{}          │ stored as ListValue                        ║
//  ╚════════════════════════╧════════════════════════════════════════════╝
//
// When converting an int64 or uint64 to a NumberValue, numeric precision loss
// is possible since they are stored as a float64.
```

For example, if you would like to produce a `Struct` that has a string list in its JSON form, you should create the following `map[string]interface{}`

```
m := map[string]interface{}{
    "name": "Anuj",
    "age":  23,
    "cars": []interface{}{
        "Toyota",
        "Honda",
        "Dodge",
    }
}
```

Sorry for the long post, I hope it makes your work easier with `proto3` and `Go`! :)

Answer (score 9):

I ended up using a two-step conversion with `protojson`, from map to json to struct:

```golang
m := map[string]interface{}{
  "foo":"bar",
  "baz":123,
}
b, err := json.Marshal(m)
s := &structpb.Struct{}
err = protojson.Unmarshal(b, s)
```

I don't find it elegant but could not really find any official documentation of how to do this differently. I also prefer to produce structures using "official" functions rather than trying to build a structure myself.

Answer (score 3):

If you have JSON data already, you could also choose to encode it as a string field.  Otherwise, using a google.protobuf.Struct seems pretty reasonable, and you should be able to use [jsonpb](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/jsonpb) to convert between the Struct and JSON easily on the client and server.

Comment: Any example on how to use `jsobpb` to a protot struct type would be helful

Comment: @Arajit 1) struct -> []byte // using json.Unmarshal. 2) proto struct -> []byte // using jsonpb package; bts:= buffers.NewBuffer(nil) jsonpb.Unmarshaler{}.Marshal(bts, yourProto). 3) []byte -> proto struct // using jsonpb package; jsonpb.Unmarshal(bytes.NewBuffer(bts), &protoStruct{})

Answer (score 0):

Don't use dynamic json. It means you have to write custom encoders for golang, it's brutal don't do it.