# Returning a json map value with grpc-gateway

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc-gateway

I am using grpc-gateway and I would like to expose an api with the following json response:

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "name": "MyItem",
  "properties": {
    "propA": 1,
    "propB": "some value",
    "propC": true,
  }
}
```

The values within "properties" are dynamic and not known ahead of time.

So far, my proto definition is:

```
message Item {
  message PropertyValue {
    string string_value = 1;
    int32 number_value = 2;
    bool bool_value = 3;
  }
  
  string id = 1;
  string name = 2;
  map<string, PropertyValue> properties = 3; 
}
```

But this yields a response like this:

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "name": "MyItem",
  "properties": {
    "propA": {
      "number_value": 1
    },
    "propB": {
      "string_value": "some value"
    },
    "propC": {
      "bool_value": true
    }
  }
}
```

How can I modify my proto so that properties is returned as a json map without the additional typing information?

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52966444/is-google-protobuf-struct-proto-the-best-way-to-send-dynamic-json-over-grpc/65026774#65026774) pointed me to google.protobuf.Struct. So I changed my message to be:

```
message Item {
  string id = 1;
  string name = 2;
  google.protobuf.Struct properties = 3; 
}
```

And this achieves what I wanted.