# Is there a way to not include @type when converting proto.Any to json?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I'd like to convert a [protobuf any type](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/google/protobuf/any.proto) to json. But the json contains the `@type` field. Is there a way I can exclude it from the result json?

For example, I have a proto definition like this

```
message Cluster {
  string name = 1;
}
```

And the following code

```
cluster := &pb.Cluster{Name: "123"}
c, _ := anypb.New(cluster)
jsonBytes, _ := protojson.Marshal(c)
log.Println(string(jsonBytes))
```

is going to print

```
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/Cluster", "name":"123"}
```

Is there a way I can exclude the `@type` field so I can get something like this?

```
{"name":"123"}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use **ANY** as field type, tag **@type** in JSON is necessary [protobuf documents](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/proto3/#json) I suggest you to use **Struct** as field type like this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52966444/is-google-protobuf-struct-proto-the-best-way-to-send-dynamic-json-over-grpc) and don't use **ANY**